# A misleading integration step.

Tags: definite-integrals

Compute $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{x^2\cos(x)}{1+e^x}$$  The first step itself  given in the solution  is changing $e^x$ to $1/e^x$ . Now as first step is making no sense to me so I didn't post the whole solution. Hope you guys help and tell me if this is some rule for definite integration.

Comment: So you want to evaluate $$\int \limits_\frac{\pi}{2}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^{2}e^{-x}\cos x dx}{1+e^{-x}}$$

Comment: Yes how to go about it

Comment: The solution substitute $x' = -x$. You can plot the functions in *Mathematica* to see what's happening (I notice the symmetry in y-axis). Consider both $x^2$ and $e^x$ are even functions.

Comment: Maybe they made the substitution $t=-x$? (With the plan of adding that integral to the original integral; that's a trick which I'm sure has been explained in other questions here. Now it's only a matter of finding them...)

Comment: Can anyone show how to evaluate this integral?

Comment: After seeing the comments I now know what's going on Thanks

Comment: i have found this approximativly result $$0.4674011002723396547086227499690377838284248518101976566033373440550112056048013107504433509296380580$$

Comment: No all answers are in $\pi$ so no problem with that.

Comment: Here are a few relevant links: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609639/an-intriguing-integral-i-int-limits-04-fracdx42x, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks/691064#691064

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=-u$

$$I=\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}-  \frac{u^2 \cos (u)}{1+e^{-u}} du= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{e^u u^2 \cos (u)}{1+e^{u}} du $$

Add the last integral to the original one gives

$$2I =\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} x^2 \cos x dx$$

Which can be dealt with using integration by part.